# OnChildRemoved Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to remove from ArrayAdapter

```
@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dataSnapshot.getKey(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String id = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    Card card1 = new Card(id);
    cardArrayAdapter.remove(card1);
    listView.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);
    cardArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If I use `cardArrayAdapter.add` in `onChildRemoved` then it will add the new child in listView. 
But `cardArrayAdatper.remove` doesn't remove from list if I removed from Firebase in `onChildAdded`

I did this

```
Card card = new Card(dataSnapshot.getKey(), lat.getValue().toString(), tempLatitude, address);
cardArrayAdapter.add(card);
listView.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);
```

Here is my DB Structure
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what type `cardArrayAdapter` is, but it seems very likely that it doesn't handle `cardArrayAdapter.remove(new Card(id));` in the way you expect it to. More likely you should look up the existing card object by its ID and then `cardArrayAdapter.remove(existingCardObject)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove a card object from an adapter, when creating a new object and expect that a particular card to be removed.

Using `cardArrayAdapter.remove(new Card(id));` means that you are removing from the adapter the card object that you have just created. What you need to do, is to find the desired card object based on the id and then remove it like this:

```
cardArrayAdapter.remove(foundedCardObject)
```

Hope it helps.